# Get the most recent record for a user

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

Say I have records like this:

```
user_id  user_data_field  created
-------  ---------------  -------
1        some data        date_a
2        some data        date_b
1        some data        date_c
1        some data        date_d
2        some data        date_e
```

What should I do to get all the user records with most recent dates only (assuming that most recent dates are not the ones at the bottom...can be anywhere)? I am using an `in_` clause to fetch the bulk users in `sqlalchemy`:

`session.query(Table).filter(Table.user_id.in_([1,2])).order_by(Table.created.desc())`

which just sorts them by the created order. Moreover, if I just add the `first()` clause at the end of this statement, it gets me just 1 row. So, do I have a way in sqlalchemy to get it done? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*@khan: you solution is almost working, but the flaw is described in the comment to your answer.*

The code below solves this particular issue (but still relies on the fact that the would not be duplicate `created` values for the same `user_id`):

```
subq = (
    session
    .query(MyTable.user_id, func.max(MyTable.created).label("max_created"))
    .filter(MyTable.user_id.in_([1, 2]))
    .group_by(MyTable.user_id)
    .subquery()
)

q = (
    session.query(MyTable)
    .join(subq, and_(MyTable.user_id == subq.c.user_id,
                     MyTable.created == subq.c.max_created))
)
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I think I have overlooked this issue, which doesn't have a very good probability of happening in my case, but still, cannot be ignored. :-) Your answer makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that the SQL query you're looking for would be something like:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(created) FROM Table WHERE user_id IN (1, 2) GROUP BY user_id;
```

So now the deal is to translate it using sqlalchemy, I'm guessing something like that would do:

```
session.query(Table.user_id, func.max(Table.created)).filter(Table.user_id.in_([1,2])).group_by(Table.user_id).all()
```

http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_1_0/core/functions.html?highlight=max#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.max

Comment: Yes, I tried that in the meanwhile when i was done posting..when i do: `session.query(Table, func.max(Table.created)).filter(Table.user_id.in_([1,2])).group_by(Table.user_id).all()` it returns the `max(created)` date, but along with it, the record that is returned is not essentially the same date, but the older one. Seems weird to me.

Comment: Thanks Seb, I figured out. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a way out, using `subquery` and a `max` function:

```
session.query(Table).filter(Table.user_id.in_([1,4])).\
filter(Table.created.in_(session.query(func.max(Table.created)).\
filter(Table.user_id.in_([1,4])).group_by(Table.user_id).subquery()))
```

In a more cleaner way, we can write out as:

```
subquery = session.query(func.max(Table.created)).\
           filter(Table.user_id.in_([1,4])).\
           group_by(Table.user_id).\
           subquery()

session.query(Table).filter(Table.user_id.in_([1,4])).filter(Table.created.in_(subq))
```

Comment: You solution has one flaw: if `created` column values are the same for different users, but for one it is the latest, while for the other it is not. In this case you will end up with multiple rows for the same `user_id`